# How to reference Instance Profile in .ebextension

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I need a queue in my elastic beanstalk application and I therefore create the queue and the queue policy with this snippet in my .ebextensions/app.conf:

```
  Resources:
    BackgroundTaskQueue:
      Type: "AWS::SQS::Queue"
    AllowWorkerSQSPolicy:
      Type: "AWS::SQS::QueuePolicy"
      Properties:
        Queues:
          -
            Ref: "BackgroundTaskQueue"
        PolicyDocument:
          Version: "2008-10-17"
          Id: "PublicationPolicy"
          Statement:
            -
              Sid: "Allow-Create-Task"
              Effect: "Allow"
              Principal:
                AWS: "*"
              Action:
                - "sqs:SendMessage"
              Resource:
                Fn::GetAtt:
                  - "BackgroundTaskQueue"
                  - "Arn"
```

Unfortunately I cannot find a way to reference the Instance profile of my EC2 instances in the autoscaling group. (At the moment the queue is open to the world) I tried two approaches:

1. Reading the configuration:

   ```
             Principal:
               AWS: 
                 Fn::GetOptionSetting:
                   OptionName: "IamInstanceProfile"
   ```

The OptionName is always retrieved from the `aws:elasticbeanstalk:customoption` namespace but the `IamInstanceProfile` is defined in the `aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration` namespace as far as I know. -> No luck

2. Reading from the actual `AWSEBAutoScalingLaunchConfiguration` resource:

   ```
             Principal:
               AWS: 
                 Fn::GetAtt:
                   - "AWSEBAutoScalingLaunchConfiguration"
                   - "IamInstanceProfile"
   ```

This approach fails cause the property `IamInstanceProfile` is not exposed.

Has anyone found a way to make such a policy work? 
Does anyone know how to instruct GetOptionSetting to look in a different namespace?
Anyone found a way to GetAtt the instance profile?

Answer (score 1):

You need setup the instances profile outside of eb environment. You can use 'aws iam' command to create policies, roles and instance profiles (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/index.html#cli-aws-iam), then specify the profile in option settings:

```
    namespace: aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration
    option_name: IamInstanceProfile
    value: your-instance-profile-name
```

If you are using eb_deployer, there is a self-contained way doing it:

Create a CloudFormation template to define your resources stack, e.g. config/my-resources.json:

```
{
  "Outputs": {
    "InstanceProfile": {
      "Description": "defines what ec2 instance can do with aws resources",
      "Value": { "Ref":  "InstanceProfile" }
    }
  },

  "Resources": {
    "Role": {
      "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
      "Properties": {
        "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
          "Statement": [{
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
              "Service": ["ec2.amazonaws.com"]
            },
            "Action": ["sts:AssumeRole"]
          }]
        },
        "Path": "/",
        "Policies": [ {
          "PolicyName": "S3Access",
          "PolicyDocument": {
            "Statement": [
              {
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": [
                  "s3:Get*",
                  "s3:List*",
                  "s3:PutObject"
                ],
                "Resource": "*"
              }
            ]
          }
        }, {
          "PolicyName": "SQSAccess",
          "PolicyDocument": {
            "Statement": [ {
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Action": [
                "sqs:ChangeMessageVisibility",
                "sqs:DeleteMessage",
                "sqs:ReceiveMessage",
                "sqs:SendMessage"
              ],
              "Resource": "*"
            }]
          }
        }]
      }
    },
    "InstanceProfile": {
      "Type": "AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile",
      "Properties": {
        "Path": "/",
        "Roles": [ { "Ref": "Role" } ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Add a "resources" section into your eb_deployer.yml

```
  resources:
    template: config/my-resources.json
    capabilities:
      - CAPABILITY_IAM
    outputs:
      InstanceProfile:
        namespace: aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration
        option_name: IamInstanceProfile
```

In the above example we defined an instance profile with policies enable specific accesses to S3 and SQS. Then map the instance profile name (output of the template) to Elastic Beanstalk option settings.

Take a look at this: https://github.com/ThoughtWorksStudios/eb_deployer/wiki/Elastic-Beanstalk-Tips-and-Tricks#setup-instance-profile-for-your-ec2-instances